# get class name before init upon class definition

Tags: python

I wonder if there is a way to get the class name automatically upon defining class attribute before initialization

```
class MyClass(object):
    attribute1 = 1
    attribute2 = 2 # This a simple example, MyClass has many other attributes
    print className # normally one would use self.__class__.__name__ but self or cls are not defined at the level

    def __init__(self):
        a = 1
```

## Purpose

In the framework I am working in, attribute1 and attribute2 are object instances (you will say everything is object oriented in python :) ) I want to set the class name to those attributes prior to MyClass initialization. MyClass get initialized a lot of times and it has much more than 2 attributes which makes the operation very time consuming to do at every initialization

Comment: Why would you need it prior to initialization? The class will not run until it is initialized so I don't really see the point.

Comment: You can use a metaclass -- But I'm not sure exactly how much that helps you since you haven't said _why_ you need the class name.  Perhaps if you tell us what you're actually trying to accomplish here we can point you in a different direction.

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do, but you should take a look at metaclasses :)

Comment: In the framework I am working in, attribute1 and attribute2 are object instances (you will say everything is object oriented in python :) ) I want to set the class name to those attributes prior to MyClass initialization. MyClass get initialized a lot of times and it has much more than 2 attributes which makes the operation very time consuming to do at every initialization

Comment: What does "set the class name to those attributes" mean? Do you mean pass the attributes to the `__init__` function? What *exactly* are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

A **metaclass** can be used to set an attribute with the class name before the class initialises:

```
class MyClassMeta(type):
    def __init__(self, name, bases, attrs):
        super(MyClassMeta, self).__init__(name, bases, attrs)
        # Set class_name to the name of our class; in this case "MyClass"
        self.class_name = name

class MyClass(object):
    __metaclass__ = MyClassMeta

    def __init__(self):
        # Prints "MyClass"
        print(self.class_name)
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6581949/3190803) for a detailed explanation of metaclasses.